# Embedding preprocessor directive into function name

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I want to embed a preprocessor directive into a function name. Basically I want to make a macro that takes a preprocessor define as argument and concatenates it's defined VALUE to get a function name.

Basically this:

```
#define PREFIX foo
#define CALL(P, x) _##P_bar(x)

...then 
CALL(PREFIX, x) should become _foo_bar(x)
```

Unfortunately this results in `_P_bar` instead of `_foo_bar`.

Is it possible to make it work as above?

Comment: Note that names in global scope that start with an underscore are reserved for the compiler and library. You are not supposed to use these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard defines special behavior for macro parameters immediately preceded and followed by ## operator. In such case they are not fully expanded. This is why your code did not behave as you expected. To further expand a parameter, you have to use it in a way that it is not immediately preceded or followed by ## operator. Try the following:

```
#define PREFIX foo
#define CALL2(P,x) _##P##_bar(x)
#define CALL(P, x) CALL2(P,x)

CALL(PREFIX, x)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `#define CALL(P,x) _##P##_bar(x)` doesn't works. I guess the issue was just identify `P` macro parameter becouse underscore hide it and the goal was do two concatenation and not just one.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Yes. I've checked it. `CALL(P,x) _##P##_bar(x)` doesn't work.